# How to fix Apache server error?

Tags: apache

I faced the Apache Web Server problem and I don't have any idea this error, so my developing environment is Centos7, apache2.4.x, php7, mssql.

Apache error log :

```
*** Error in `/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f5fa90591f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d56d)[0x7f5fae39956d]
/lib64/libdl.so.2(+0x1655)[0x7f5fae6de655]
/lib64/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x31)[0x7f5fae6de0c1]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0x5345a)[0x7f5fa8a9545a]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0x5012a)[0x7f5fa8a9212a]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0x51a43)[0x7f5fa8a93a43]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0x524aa)[0x7f5fa8a944aa]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0xc5f0)[0x7f5fa8a4e5f0]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(+0xcc52)[0x7f5fa8a4ec52]
/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1(SQLConnect+0x18d)[0x7f5fa8a517fd]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(+0x2f1716)[0x7f5faa801716]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(+0x2e81dc)[0x7f5faa7f81dc]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(+0x4e8c54)[0x7f5faa9f8c54]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(execute_ex+0x1b)[0x7f5faa9b4b9b]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(zend_execute+0x249)[0x7f5faaa06119]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(zend_execute_scripts+0xe7)[0x7f5faa9743e7]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(php_execute_script+0x380)[0x7f5faa908c10]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so(+0x4f80a2)[0x7f5faaa080a2]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_run_handler+0x40)[0x44edc0]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_invoke_handler+0x69)[0x44f309]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_internal_redirect+0x4c)[0x46337c]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so(+0x4dac)[0x7f5fab29edac]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_run_handler+0x40)[0x44edc0]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_invoke_handler+0x69)[0x44f309]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_process_async_request+0x1ea)[0x463fca]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd[0x4605a1]
/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd(ap_run_process_connection+0x40)[0x458700]
/usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so(+0x7ade)[0x7f5fabeceade]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7df3)[0x7f5fae8e8df3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f5fae4123dd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0048b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 34262381                           /usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd
0068a000-0068b000 r--p 0008a000 08:01 34262381                           /usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd
0068b000-00690000 rw-p 0008b000 08:01 34262381                           /usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd
00690000-00693000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01a12000-01ab8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
01ab8000-01f6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f5f8c000000-7f5f8c117000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f8c117000-7f5f90000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f92a00000-7f5f92e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f92fe6000-7f5f92fe7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f92fe7000-7f5f937e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18509]
7f5f937e7000-7f5f937e8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f937e8000-7f5f93fe8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18507]
7f5f93fe8000-7f5f93fe9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f93fe9000-7f5f947e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18505]
7f5f947e9000-7f5f947ea000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f947ea000-7f5f94fea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18503]
7f5f94fea000-7f5f94feb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f94feb000-7f5f957eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18501]
7f5f957eb000-7f5f957ec000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f957ec000-7f5f95fec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18499]
7f5f95fec000-7f5f95fed000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f95fed000-7f5f967ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18497]
7f5f967ed000-7f5f967ee000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f967ee000-7f5f96fee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18496]
7f5f96fee000-7f5f96fef000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f96fef000-7f5f977ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18493]
7f5f977ef000-7f5f977f0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f977f0000-7f5f97ff0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18491]
7f5f97ff0000-7f5f97ff1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f97ff1000-7f5f987f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18489]
7f5f987f1000-7f5f987f2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f987f2000-7f5f98ff2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18487]
7f5f98ff2000-7f5f98ff3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f98ff3000-7f5f997f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18485]
7f5f997f3000-7f5f997f4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f997f4000-7f5f99ff4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18483]
7f5f99ff4000-7f5f99ff5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f99ff5000-7f5f9a7f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18481]
7f5f9a7f5000-7f5f9a7f6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9a7f6000-7f5f9aff6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18479]
7f5f9aff6000-7f5f9aff7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9aff7000-7f5f9b7f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18477]
7f5f9b7f7000-7f5f9b7f8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9b7f8000-7f5f9bff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18475]
7f5f9bff8000-7f5f9bff9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9bff9000-7f5f9c7f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18473]
7f5f9c7f9000-7f5f9c7fa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9c7fa000-7f5f9cffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18472]
7f5f9cffa000-7f5f9cffb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9cffb000-7f5f9d7fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18470]
7f5f9d7fb000-7f5f9d7fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9d7fc000-7f5f9dffc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18467]
7f5f9dffc000-7f5f9dffd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9dffd000-7f5f9e7fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18466]
7f5f9e7fd000-7f5f9e7fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9e7fe000-7f5f9effe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18464]
7f5f9effe000-7f5f9efff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9efff000-7f5f9f7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18463]
7f5f9f7ff000-7f5f9f800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9f800000-7f5fa0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:18459]
7f5fa0000000-7f5fa0038000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa0038000-7f5fa4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa40ad000-7f5fa40af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12586202                   /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
7f5fa40af000-7f5fa42af000 ---p 00002000 08:01 12586202                   /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
7f5fa42af000-7f5fa42b0000 r--p 00002000 08:01 12586202                   /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
7f5fa42b0000-7f5fa42b1000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 12586202                   /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
7f5fa42b1000-7f5fa42c6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10278                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f5fa42c6000-7f5fa44c5000 ---p 00015000 08:01 10278                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f5fa44c5000-7f5fa44c6000 r--p 00014000 08:01 10278                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f5fa44c6000-7f5fa44c7000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 10278                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f5fa44c7000-7f5fa44c8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa44c8000-7f5fa4cc8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa4cc8000-7f5fa4d02000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3266                       /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
7f5fa4d02000-7f5fa4f01000 ---p 0003a000 08:01 3266                       /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
7f5fa4f01000-7f5fa4f02000 r--p 00039000 08:01 3266                       /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
7f5fa4f02000-7f5fa4f04000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 3266                       /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
7f5fa4f04000-7f5fa4f06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa4f06000-7f5fa4f0a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3296                       /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
7f5fa4f0a000-7f5fa5109000 ---p 00004000 08:01 3296                       /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
7f5fa5109000-7f5fa510a000 r--p 00003000 08:01 3296                       /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
7f5fa510a000-7f5fa510b000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 3296                       /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
7f5fa510b000-7f5fa510e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3309                       /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
7f5fa510e000-7f5fa530d000 ---p 00003000 08:01 3309                       /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
7f5fa530d000-7f5fa530e000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3309                       /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
7f5fa530e000-7f5fa530f000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3309                       /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
7f5fa530f000-7f5fa5335000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3355                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f5fa5335000-7f5fa5534000 ---p 00026000 08:01 3355                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f5fa5534000-7f5fa553a000 r--p 00025000 08:01 3355                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f5fa553a000-7f5fa553b000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 3355                       /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
7f5fa553b000-7f5fa5659000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10262                      /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f5fa5659000-7f5fa5858000 ---p 0011e000 08:01 10262                      /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f5fa5858000-7f5fa585d000 r--p 0011d000 08:01 10262                      /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f5fa585d000-7f5fa585f000 rw-p 00122000 08:01 10262                      /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
7f5fa585f000-7f5fa5861000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa5861000-7f5fa5885000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10264                      /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f5fa5885000-7f5fa5a84000 ---p 00024000 08:01 10264                      /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f5fa5a84000-7f5fa5a87000 r--p 00023000 08:01 10264                      /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f5fa5a87000-7f5fa5a88000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 10264                      /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
7f5fa5a88000-7f5fa5ac6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10265                      /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f5fa5ac6000-7f5fa5cc6000 ---p 0003e000 08:01 10265                      /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f5fa5cc6000-7f5fa5cc9000 r--p 0003e000 08:01 10265                      /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f5fa5cc9000-7f5fa5cca000 rw-p 00041000 08:01 10265                      /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
7f5fa5cca000-7f5fa5ccb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa5ccb000-7f5fa5ce7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 593959                     /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0
7f5fa5ce7000-7f5fa5ee6000 ---p 0001c000 08:01 593959                     /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0
7f5fa5ee6000-7f5fa5ee7000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 593959                     /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0
7f5fa5ee7000-7f5fa5ee8000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 593959                     /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0
7f5fa5ee8000-7f5fa5f38000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 593963                     /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa5f38000-7f5fa6137000 ---p 00050000 08:01 593963                     /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa6137000-7f5fa613a000 r--p 0004f000 08:01 593963                     /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa613a000-7f5fa613b000 rw-p 00052000 08:01 593963                     /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa613b000-7f5fa6149000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 593961                     /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa6149000-7f5fa6348000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 593961                     /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa6348000-7f5fa6349000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 593961                     /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa6349000-7f5fa634a000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 593961                     /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.3
7f5fa634a000-7f5fa63b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17083436                   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f5fa63b0000-7f5fa65af000 ---p 00066000 08:01 17083436                   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f5fa65af000-7f5fa65b1000 r--p 00065000 08:01 17083436                   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f5fa65b1000-7f5fa65b2000 rw-p 00067000 08:01 17083436                   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f5fa65b2000-7f5fa65c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17077313                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/curl.so
7f5fa65c5000-7f5fa67c5000 ---p 00013000 08:01 17077313                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/curl.so
7f5fa67c5000-7f5fa67c7000 r--p 00013000 08:01 17077313                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/curl.so
7f5fa67c7000-7f5fa67c8000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 17077313                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/curl.so
7f5fa67c8000-7f5fa6830000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17077352                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/redis.so
7f5fa6830000-7f5fa6a2f000 ---p 00068000 08:01 17077352                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/redis.so
7f5fa6a2f000-7f5fa6a30000 r--p 00067000 08:01 17077352                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/redis.so
7f5fa6a30000-7f5fa6a34000 rw-p 00068000 08:01 17077352                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/redis.so
7f5fa6a34000-7f5fa6a35000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa6a35000-7f5fa6a59000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634899                     /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f5fa6a59000-7f5fa6c58000 ---p 00024000 08:01 634899                     /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f5fa6c58000-7f5fa6c59000 r--p 00023000 08:01 634899                     /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f5fa6c59000-7f5fa6c5a000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 634899                     /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7f5fa6c5a000-7f5fa6c5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa6c5c000-7f5fa6c5f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6216                       /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5fa6c5f000-7f5fa6e5e000 ---p 00003000 08:01 6216                       /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5fa6e5e000-7f5fa6e5f000 r--p 00002000 08:01 6216                       /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5fa6e5f000-7f5fa6e60000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 6216                       /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f5fa6e60000-7f5fa6e6d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634921                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5fa6e6d000-7f5fa706d000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 634921                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5fa706d000-7f5fa706e000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 634921                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5fa706e000-7f5fa706f000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 634921                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f5fa706f000-7f5fa709e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634913                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5fa709e000-7f5fa729d000 ---p 0002f000 08:01 634913                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5fa729d000-7f5fa729f000 r--p 0002e000 08:01 634913                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5fa729f000-7f5fa72a0000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 634913                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f5fa72a0000-7f5fa72a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa72a1000-7f5fa72a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3295                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5fa72a4000-7f5fa74a3000 ---p 00003000 08:01 3295                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5fa74a3000-7f5fa74a4000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3295                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5fa74a4000-7f5fa74a5000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3295                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f5fa74a5000-7f5fa757b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634919                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5fa757b000-7f5fa777b000 ---p 000d6000 08:01 634919                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5fa777b000-7f5fa7789000 r--p 000d6000 08:01 634919                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5fa7789000-7f5fa778c000 rw-p 000e4000 08:01 634919                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f5fa778c000-7f5fa77d7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634909                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5fa77d7000-7f5fa79d7000 ---p 0004b000 08:01 634909                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5fa79d7000-7f5fa79d8000 r--p 0004b000 08:01 634909                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5fa79d8000-7f5fa79da000 rw-p 0004c000 08:01 634909                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f5fa79da000-7f5fa79e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3192                       /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f5fa79e5000-7f5fa7be4000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 3192                       /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f5fa7be4000-7f5fa7be5000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 3192                       /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f5fa7be5000-7f5fa7be6000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 3192                       /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f5fa7d84000-7f5fa7f44000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634904                     /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa7f44000-7f5fa8144000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 634904                     /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa8144000-7f5fa815e000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 634904                     /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa815e000-7f5fa816a000 rw-p 001da000 08:01 634904                     /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa816a000-7f5fa816e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa816e000-7f5fa81d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634906                     /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa81d2000-7f5fa83d1000 ---p 00064000 08:01 634906                     /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa83d1000-7f5fa83d5000 r--p 00063000 08:01 634906                     /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa83d5000-7f5fa83dc000 rw-p 00067000 08:01 634906                     /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
7f5fa83dc000-7f5fa83fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17077349                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/openssl.so
7f5fa83fc000-7f5fa85fc000 ---p 00020000 08:01 17077349                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/openssl.so
7f5fa85fc000-7f5fa85fe000 r--p 00020000 08:01 17077349                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/openssl.so
7f5fa85fe000-7f5fa85ff000 rw-p 00022000 08:01 17077349                   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/openssl.so
7f5fa85ff000-7f5fa8600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa8600000-7f5fa8800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa881c000-7f5fa8841000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6171                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2
7f5fa8841000-7f5fa8a40000 ---p 00025000 08:01 6171                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2
7f5fa8a40000-7f5fa8a41000 r--p 00024000 08:01 6171                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2
7f5fa8a41000-7f5fa8a42000 rw-p 00025000 08:01 6171                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2
7f5fa8a42000-7f5fa8aa5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 735285                     /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7f5fa8aa5000-7f5fa8ca5000 ---p 00063000 08:01 735285                     /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7f5fa8ca5000-7f5fa8ca7000 r--p 00063000 08:01 735285                     /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7f5fa8ca7000-7f5fa8cad000 rw-p 00065000 08:01 735285                     /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7f5fa8cad000-7f5fa8cae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa8cae000-7f5fa8d4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6169                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.10.0
7f5fa8d4e000-7f5fa8f4d000 ---p 000a0000 08:01 6169                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.10.0
7f5fa8f4d000-7f5fa8f53000 r--p 0009f000 08:01 6169                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.10.0
7f5fa8f53000-7f5fa8f54000 rw-p 000a5000 08:01 6169                       /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.10.0
7f5fa8f54000-7f5fa90b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10274                      /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f5fa90b3000-7f5fa92b2000 ---p 0015f000 08:01 10274                      /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f5fa92b2000-7f5fa92ba000 r--p 0015e000 08:01 10274                      /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f5fa92ba000-7f5fa92bc000 rw-p 00166000 08:01 10274                      /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.9.1
7f5fa92bc000-7f5fa92be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa92be000-7f5fa92d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3184                       /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
7f5fa92d4000-7f5fa94d3000 ---p 00016000 08:01 3184                       /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
7f5fa94d3000-7f5fa94d4000 r--p 00015000 08:01 3184                       /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
7f5fa94d4000-7f5fa94d5000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 3184                       /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
7f5fa94d5000-7f5fa94d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa94d7000-7f5fa95d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3182                       /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f5fa95d8000-7f5fa97d7000 ---p 00101000 08:01 3182                       /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f5fa97d7000-7f5fa97d8000 r--p 00100000 08:01 3182                       /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f5fa97d8000-7f5fa97d9000 rw-p 00101000 08:01 3182                       /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f5fa97d9000-7f5fa97e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3293                       /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
7f5fa97e8000-7f5fa99e7000 ---p 0000f000 08:01 3293                       /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
7f5fa99e7000-7f5fa99e8000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 3293                       /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
7f5fa99e8000-7f5fa99e9000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 3293                       /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
7f5fa99e9000-7f5fa9a2c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 73745                      /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.1.0
7f5fa9a2c000-7f5fa9c2c000 ---p 00043000 08:01 73745                      /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.1.0
7f5fa9c2c000-7f5fa9c2d000 r--p 00043000 08:01 73745                      /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.1.0
7f5fa9c2d000-7f5fa9c2e000 rw-p 00044000 08:01 73745                      /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.1.0
7f5fa9c2e000-7f5fa9c3e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa9c3e000-7f5fa9c53000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 634889                     /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
7f5fa9c53000-7f5fa9e52000 ---p 00015000 08:01 634889                     /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
7f5fa9e52000-7f5fa9e53000 r--p 00014000 08:01 634889                     /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
7f5fa9e53000-7f5fa9e54000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 634889                     /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
7f5fa9e54000-7f5fa9e7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 550022                     /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15.13.0
7f5fa9e7d000-7f5faa07d000 ---p 00029000 08:01 550022                     /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15.13.0
7f5faa07d000-7f5faa07e000 r--p 00029000 08:01 550022                     /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15.13.0
7f5faa07e000-7f5faa07f000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 550022                     /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15.13.0
7f5faa07f000-7f5faa0f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3316                       /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7f5faa0f5000-7f5faa2f4000 ---p 00076000 08:01 3316                       /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7f5faa2f4000-7f5faa2f5000 r--p 00075000 08:01 3316                       /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7f5faa2f5000-7f5faa2f6000 rw-p 00076000 08:01 3316                       /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7f5faa2f6000-7f5faa30c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3202                       /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f5faa30c000-7f5faa50c000 ---p 00016000 08:01 3202                       /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f5faa50c000-7f5faa50d000 r--p 00016000 08:01 3202                       /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f5faa50d000-7f5faa50e000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 3202                       /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f5faa50e000-7f5faa510000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5faa510000-7f5faafcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29706327                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
7f5faafcf000-7f5fab1cf000 ---p 00abf000 08:01 29706327                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
7f5fab1cf000-7f5fab267000 r--p 00abf000 08:01 29706327                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
7f5fab267000-7f5fab27f000 rw-p 00b57000 08:01 29706327                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
7f5fab27f000-7f5fab29a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fab29a000-7f5fab2aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674743                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f5fab2aa000-7f5fab4a9000 ---p 00010000 08:01 29674743                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f5fab4a9000-7f5fab4aa000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 29674743                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f5fab4aa000-7f5fab4ab000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 29674743                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
7f5fab4ab000-7f5fab4af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674742                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
7f5fab4af000-7f5fab6ae000 ---p 00004000 08:01 29674742                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
7f5fab6ae000-7f5fab6af000 r--p 00003000 08:01 29674742                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
7f5fab6af000-7f5fab6b0000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 29674742                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
7f5fab6b0000-7f5fab6b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674738                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
7f5fab6b2000-7f5fab8b1000 ---p 00002000 08:01 29674738                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
7f5fab8b1000-7f5fab8b2000 r--p 00001000 08:01 29674738                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
7f5fab8b2000-7f5fab8b3000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 29674738                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
7f5fab8b3000-7f5fab8bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674732                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
7f5fab8bb000-7f5fababb000 ---p 00008000 08:01 29674732                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
7f5fababb000-7f5fababc000 r--p 00008000 08:01 29674732                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
7f5fababc000-7f5fababd000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 29674732                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
7f5fababd000-7f5fabac2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674731                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
7f5fabac2000-7f5fabcc1000 ---p 00005000 08:01 29674731                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
7f5fabcc1000-7f5fabcc2000 r--p 00004000 08:01 29674731                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
7f5fabcc2000-7f5fabcc3000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 29674731                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
7f5fabcc3000-7f5fabcc6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674729                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
7f5fabcc6000-7f5fabec5000 ---p 00003000 08:01 29674729                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
7f5fabec5000-7f5fabec6000 r--p 00002000 08:01 29674729                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
7f5fabec6000-7f5fabec7000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 29674729                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
7f5fabec7000-7f5fabed6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29391935                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
7f5fabed6000-7f5fac0d5000 ---p 0000f000 08:01 29391935                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
7f5fac0d5000-7f5fac0d6000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 29391935                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
7f5fac0d6000-7f5fac0d7000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 29391935                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
7f5fac0d7000-7f5fac0d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674706                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
7f5fac0d9000-7f5fac2d8000 ---p 00002000 08:01 29674706                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
7f5fac2d8000-7f5fac2d9000 r--p 00001000 08:01 29674706                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
7f5fac2d9000-7f5fac2da000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 29674706                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
7f5fac2da000-7f5fac2dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674705                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f5fac2dd000-7f5fac4dc000 ---p 00003000 08:01 29674705                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f5fac4dc000-7f5fac4dd000 r--p 00002000 08:01 29674705                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f5fac4dd000-7f5fac4de000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 29674705                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
7f5fac4de000-7f5fac4e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674703                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
7f5fac4e2000-7f5fac6e2000 ---p 00004000 08:01 29674703                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
7f5fac6e2000-7f5fac6e3000 r--p 00004000 08:01 29674703                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
7f5fac6e3000-7f5fac6e4000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 29674703                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
7f5fac6e4000-7f5fac6e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29674700                   /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_env.so
.
.
.
.
```

I want to know why it occur and how I can resolve it.

Comment: From log:
`/usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`
and
 `/usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so`. 
Are you trying to run PHP module with threaded MPM? It will not [work correctly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP). Can you share your MPM and PHP configuration?

Comment: My PHP configuration is

Comment: ./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd/bin/apxs' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/httpd' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-ftp' '--disable-debug' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-mod-charset' '--enable-sysvsem=yes' '--enable-sysvshm=yes' '--with-iconv' '--with-gmp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-exif' '--enable-sigchild' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-gd' '--with-bz2' '--with-zlib' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib' '--with-png-dir=/usr/lib' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2' '

Comment: --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/tmp/unixODBC.27464.20978.26522/unixODBC-2.3.0

Comment: And I use mpm_event_module And Setting is..

Comment: <IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers            15
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads         250
    ThreadsPerChild         64
    MaxRequestWorkers       384
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Comment: It looks like you don't have `--enable-maintainer-zts` in your PHP build. Therefore, I would suggest using **prefork MPM** instead of **event MPM**. Simple how to in following link:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP

Comment: Thanks Nomad
I looked your opinion
I thought modifying PHP configuration better than modifying MPM
So, I changed my PHP configuration then I will keep an eye

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://serverfault.com/questions/169829/what-does-glibc-detected-httpd-double-free-or-corruption-mean) a maybe explanation for what you're facing. Apparently you're trying to free already freed memory.